# How to save the grep o many files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am using grep to catch a part of many files, which has name 001.log, 002.log, 003.log ....

I need to save the grep as a different file

```
 grep -A3406 -P 'Molecular' *.log
```

And to output the grep in files with the name 001a.log, 002a.log, 003a.log ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect the grep's output to a file:

```
grep -A3406 -P 'Molecular' *.log > new_file
```

You can then process the new file and split it on the file name change (or just pipe the output to the splitting script). More details would be needed to give a working example.

Or, process the files one by one (would be a bit slower):

```
for file in *.log ; do
    grep -A3406 -P 'Molecular' "$file" > "${file%.log}a.log"
done
```

Also, you don't need `-P` for a simple regex like `Molecular`.

Comment: @alloppp: You can try the second option if you don't want to post-process the single file.